# El recurso requerido no está disponible en tomcat

Tags: java, servlets

Mi problema es el siguiente, al hacer click en el boton "Mostrar Clientes" de FormularioJSP.jsp me muestra el siguiente error, el cual me parece que la ruta esta escrita correctamente, o quizas me falta algo mas
[image: Lo que me muestra]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**FormularioJSP.jsp**

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario de Prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Datos del cliente</h1>
        <form action="SVPrueba" method="POST">
            <p><label>Dni: </label> <input type="text" name="dni"></p>
            <p><label>Nombre: </label> <input type="text" name="nombre"></p>
            <p><label>Apellido: </label> <input type="text" name="apellido"></p>
            <p><label>Telefono: </label> <input type="text" name="telefono"></p>
            <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>
        </form>
        <h1>Ver lista de clientes</h1>
        <p>Si desea ver todos los clientes haga click en el boton mostrar cleintes</p>
        <form action="SVPrueba" method="GET">
            <button type="submit">Mostrar Clientes</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MostrarJSP.jsp**

```
    <%@page import="Clases.Cliente"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Clientes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lista Clientes</h1>
        <%-- utilizaremos codigo java para traer y recorrer la lista --%>
        
        <% 
          List <Cliente> listaClientes = (List) request.getSession().getAttribute("listaClientes");
          int cont = 1;
          for (Cliente cli : listaClientes){ %>
          <p><b>Cliente N° <%=cont%></b></p>
          <p>Dni: <%=cli.getDni()%></p>
          <p>Nombre <%=cli.getNombre()%></p>
          <p>Apellido <%=cli.getApellido()%></p>
          <p>Telefono <%=cli.getTelefono()%></p>
              
          <%-- Incremento mi contador,
          para mostrar correctamente cada num de cliente
          --%>
          <% cont = cont + 1;%>
          <%}%>    
          
    </body>
</html>
```

**SVPrueba.java**

```
 package Servlets;

import Clases.Cliente;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "SVPrueba", urlPatterns = {"/SVPrueba"})
public class SVPrueba extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SVPrueba</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet SVPrueba at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //simulamos una lista de clientes
        //esto ya podria venir desde una base de datos
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
        listaClientes.add(new Cliente("12345678","Lusina","de Paula","444222357"));
        listaClientes.add(new Cliente("39887451","Avril","Lavigne","1112223336"));
        listaClientes.add(new Cliente("99999999","Valentin","Olivos","963158758"));
        
        //seteamos la lista de clientes como un parametro
        //para poder utilizar en cualquier JSP
        //para ello traemos la sesion de la request
        HttpSession misession = request.getSession();
        misession.setAttribute("listaClientes", listaClientes);
        
        //redisreccionamos a otro JSP
        response.sendRedirect("MostrarJSP.jsp");
        
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //traemos los datos enviados en la request 
        //los guardamos en variables auxiliares
        //el nombre en getParameter debe ser el mismo que en el input del form
        
        String dni = request.getParameter("dni");
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
        String telefono = request.getParameter("telefono");
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

La verdad recién voy comenzando con esto, no sé si la dirección esta mal en el form o falta algo mas. Los mismos me sucede cuando completo el formulario y hago click en el boton "Enviar".
Estoy trabajando desde Apache netbeans.

Nota: la aplicacon comienza a ejecutarse desde FormularioJSP.jsp

Comment: Falta ver tu `web.xml`. No es evidente el cómo defines el servlet

Comment: Disculpa, donde puedo encontrar eso?

Comment: Ese archivo debe estar en tu proyecto. Dentro de `/WEB-INF`, normalmente

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre mi solucion el problema estaba en el servler cuando se importa javax, al parecer ya no es compatible y lo cambie por jakarta

Antes

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
```

Lo cambie por

```
import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Y listo, todo solucionado!